# remove node from XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I've below `XML` in my `web.config`

```
 <handlers>
  <remove name="ChartImageHandler" />            
  <add name="PageNotFoundhandelarrtf" path="*.rtf" verb="*" 
     modules="IsapiModule"  scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\
     aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified"  preCondition=
     "classicMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness32" />
  <add name="ChartImageHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ChartImg.axd" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization,  Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  <add name="Keyoti_SearchEngine_Web_CallBackHandler_ashx" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" path="Keyoti.SearchEngine.Web.CallBackHandler.ashx" type="Keyoti.SearchEngine.Web.CallBackHandler, Keyoti2.SearchEngine.Web, Version=2012.5.12.706, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=58d9fd2e9ec4dc0e" />
  <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" 
     verb="*"  type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler,
     Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,  PublicKeyToken
     =b03f5f7f11d50a3a" validate="false" />
 </handlers>
```

And i need to remove last node from this `XML` for `ReportViewer` in `<handler>` section. I first need to find `<handler>` section than above node should be removed.

I'm using below code but its not working...can you please guide me what's wrong with the below piece of code..

```
XElement xEmp = XElement.Load(PATH + WEB_CONFIG_PATH);
var empDetails = from emps in xEmp.Elements("handlers")
                 where emps.Element("path").Equals("Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd")
                 select emps;
empDetails.First().Remove();
xEmp.Save(@"D:\Employees.xml");
```

Comment: "Not working" isn't very helpful - are you getting an exception, or does your code run without changing anything?

Comment: I ain't getting any exception..its just simply not working for above `XML`.and Yes code runs with changing anything...

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use next code snippet

```
XElement xEmp = XElement.Load(PATH + WEB_CONFIG_PATH);
var pathToRemove = "Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd";

var empDetails= xEmp.XPathSelectElements("//handlers")
                    .Descendants()
                    .First(d => d.Attributes().Any(atr => atr.Name == "path" && atr.Value == pathToRemove));

empDetails.Remove();
xEmp.Save(@"D:\Employees.xml");
```

If you want to stick with query syntax, you still have to mix it a little bit:

```
var empDetails = from emps in xEmp.XPathSelectElements("//handlers").Descendants()
                 where emps.Attributes().Any(atr => atr.Name == "path" && atr.Value == pathToRemove)
                 select emps;
```

Comment: Sorry...i've updated my question..it should first find `<handlers>` section and than remove the node..and your code will remove all the nodes from anywhere..

Comment: In all `<handlers>` section?

Comment: and `<handlers>` is not the root of the document?

Comment: I have updated my answer with respect to this issue. Note that it will throws exception if not `handlers` section will be present in `config` file or `handlers` will be the root element or will be nested deeper. Is it ok?

Comment: @MayankPathak I've updated my answer to select nodes regardless of their location. Give it a try

Answer (score 0):

I ran this code an it seems to work.  Here's what I did . . .

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(INPUT_DATA);
XElement handlers = doc.Element("handlers");
IEnumerable<XElement> add = null;
IEnumerable<XElement> pFind = null;

if (handlers != null)
{             
    add = handlers.Elements();
    if (add != null)
    {

        pFind = (from itm in add
                    where itm.Attribute("path") != null
                    && itm.Attribute("path").Value != null
                    && itm.Attribute("path").Value == "Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd"
                    select itm);

        if(pFind != null)
            pFind.FirstOrDefault().Remove();
    }
}
```

here is the full tested code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace XDocu
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(INPUT_DATA);
        XElement handlers = doc.Element("handlers");
        IEnumerable<XElement> add = null;
        IEnumerable<XElement> pFind = null;
        int oldCount = doc.Element("handlers").Elements().Count();

        if (handlers != null)
        {             
            add = handlers.Elements();
            if (add != null)
            {

                pFind = (from itm in add
                            where itm.Attribute("path") != null
                            && itm.Attribute("path").Value != null
                            && itm.Attribute("path").Value == "Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd"
                            select itm);

                if(pFind != null)
                    pFind.LastOrDefault().Remove();
            }
        }

            //print it
            if (add != null)
                Console.WriteLine("Old Count: {0}\nNew Count: {1}", oldCount, add.Count());
        }

        const string INPUT_DATA =
        @"<?xml version=""1.0""?>
        <handlers>
        <remove name=""ChartImageHandler"" />            
        <add name=""PageNotFoundhandelarrtf"" path=""*.rtf"" verb=""*"" 
            modules=""IsapiModule""  scriptProcessor=""%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\
            aspnet_isapi.dll"" resourceType=""Unspecified""  preCondition=
            ""classicMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness32"" />
        <add name=""ChartImageHandler"" preCondition=""integratedMode"" verb=""GET,HEAD"" path=""ChartImg.axd"" type=""System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization,  Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"" />
        <add name=""Keyoti_SearchEngine_Web_CallBackHandler_ashx"" verb=""*"" preCondition=""integratedMode"" path=""Keyoti.SearchEngine.Web.CallBackHandler.ashx"" type=""Keyoti.SearchEngine.Web.CallBackHandler, Keyoti2.SearchEngine.Web, Version=2012.5.12.706, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=58d9fd2e9ec4dc0e"" />
        <add path=""Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd"" 
            verb=""*""  type=""Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler,
            Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,  PublicKeyToken
            =b03f5f7f11d50a3a"" validate=""false"" />
        </handlers>";

    }
}
```

Compiler shows output that removes the item based on your critera correctly, we are left with . . .

```
<handlers>
  <remove name="ChartImageHandler" />
  <add name="PageNotFoundhandelarrtf" path="*.rtf" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\             aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness32" />
  <add name="ChartImageHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ChartImg.axd" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization,  Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  <add name="Keyoti_SearchEngine_Web_CallBackHandler_ashx" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" path="Keyoti.SearchEngine.Web.CallBackHandler.ashx" type="Keyoti.SearchEngine.Web.CallBackHandler, Keyoti2.SearchEngine.Web, Version=2012.5.12.706, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=58d9fd2e9ec4dc0e" />
</handlers>
```

That is, with the exclusion of `<Add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" . . . />`

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the node from XML file is given here: http://www.wrangle.in/topic/asw0zgftjzqr/C-Sharp-tricks-deleting-node-from-xml-fi